# Test for Independence

Tags: probability

The question is

A pair of fice is rolled. Each die has the following probability distribution [image]

Let E be the event where the sum of the two dice is equal to 4 and Let A be the event that the first die lands on 3. Show whether events A and E are independent

My solution:

E=(3,1),(2,2),(1,3)- number of ways to get the sum to be 4
For each outcome, i multiplied their probability and added them to get the $P(E)$ i.e

$(3,1)=0.1*0.1=0.01$

$(2,2)=0.2*0.2=0.04$

$(1,3)=0.01$
hence the total of $P(E)=0.06$

$A={(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6)}$

$P(A)=0.1$

$AnE={(3,1)}$

$P(AnE)=0.01$

$P(A)P(E)$=0.006

$P(AnE)!=P(A)P(E)$

as 0.01!=0.006

Hence they are dependant?

is this the correct way to this especially the working out. (Refer to the working above )

At first i had it worked out like this but apparently this is wrong but why?
[image]

Comment: I tried updating and correctly present my solution as neat as possible please let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Well you have events $E$ and $A$ and then $B$ and then back to $E$ again, so I think you should change to just $A$ and $E$.

Comment: Also you have probabilities $0.1$ and so on in the table but then in the paper working you have probabilities more like $\frac16$, you have $P(A\cap E)=1/36$ which isn't compatible with the table you posted.

Comment: My main working out is at the top of the paper solution and I know the paper solution is wrong as it only applies to a fair dice is my understanding correct ?

Comment: If you already know that it's wrong then it might make things easier if you don't post it.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from your posting.

$A$ and $B$ are independent events if and only if $p(A) = p(A|B).$

- By your analysis, $p(A) = 0.06$.
- It is easy to see that $p(A|B) = 0.1$. 
  That is, if the first roll is a $(3)$ the sum will be four if and only if the second roll is a $(1)$.

$(0.06)$ is not equal to $(0.1)$.  This makes the events not independent.  That is (informally), the fact that event $B$ (rolling a three) has occurred has **altered** the probability of whether the sum will equal four.